# Why does XmlDocument.validate incorrectly validate an invalid xml document with empty namespaces?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm trying to validate a XML document I'm creating in the code before i save it. However my code always pass through the validation with no problem even when i input incorrect value on purpose. What is the problem with the code?

```
private XmlDocument xmlDocChanges = new XmlDocument();
   public void Validate()
   {
        xmlDocChanges.Schemas.Add("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "xsd/Customization.xsd");
        ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);
        xmlDocChanges.Validate(eventHandler);
   }
   public void ValidationCallBack (object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
   {
       if(args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error || args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
       {
           throw new Exception(args.Exception.Message);
       }
   }
```

EDIT
Example XSD.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="FirstNode">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>First node</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:attribute name="Identifier" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="Bool" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

XML

```
<Customizations FormatVersion="1" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Customization.xsd">
  <Customization>
    <Application name="App">
      <FirstNode Identifier="one" Bool="NoValue"></FirstNode>
    </Application>
  </Customization>
</Customizations>
```

Comment: Are those methods ever executed? If so provide schema and xml that you validate.

Comment: Can you please add an example for XSD and XML files in use.

Comment: Validate is being executed and ValidationCallBack is only executed if something went wrong with the validation.

Comment: From the msdn documentation:

These events occur while reading an XML instance document if the ValidationType is set to either DTD or Schema

Are you setting ValidationType to DTD or Schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I had to send a empty namespace parameter in the add method.

```
    public void Validate()
    {
        xmlDocChanges.Schemas.Add("", "xsd/Customization.xsd");
        ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack);
        xmlDocChanges.Validate(eventHandler);
    }
    public void ValidationCallBack (object sender, ValidationEventArgs args)
    {
        if(args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error || args.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
        {
            throw new Exception(args.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your schema has no `targetNamespace`, so the original `xmlDocChanges.Schema.Add("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", ...)` just bound a namespace you were not using to your `Customization.xsd` schema. The `targetNamespace` of the types in your schema must match the namespace of the types in your xml, and of course, the namespace that you bind with `XmlDocument.Schemas.Add()`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method I use for validating xml with a schema

```
public static Tuple<bool, string> ValidateXml(string xmlSchemaFile, string sourceXml) {

        var internalValidationErrors = new XmlSchemaValidationErrorCollection();
        ValidationEventHandler handler = (sender, args) => internalValidationErrors.Add(args);
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema };

        try {
            // Set the validation settings. 
            settings = new XmlReaderSettings { ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema };
            settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
            settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
            settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
            settings.ValidationEventHandler += handler;

            using(var reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlSchemaFile)) {
                settings.Schemas.Add(null, reader);
            }

            if(settings.Schemas.Count == 0)
                return Tuple.Create(false, "Missing schema file.");

            // Create the XmlReader object for xml
            using(var reader = XmlReader.Create(sourceXml, settings)) {
                // Parse the file.  
                while(reader.Read()) {}
            }

            var validationErrors = internalValidationErrors;

            return Tuple.Create(validationErrors.Any(), validationErrors.ToString());
        }
        finally {
            settings.ValidationEventHandler -= handler;
        }
    }

public class XmlSchemaValidationErrorCollection : List<ValidationEventArgs>
{
    internal XmlSchemaValidationErrorCollection()
    { }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var validationError in this)
        {
            builder.Append("-Validation Error-");
            builder.AppendFormat("Message: {0} \r\n", validationError.Message);
            builder.AppendFormat("Severity: {0} \r\n", Enum.GetName(typeof(XmlSeverityType), validationError.Severity));
            builder.AppendFormat("Exception: {0} \r\n", validationError.Exception.GetDeepMessage());
            builder.Append("\r\n");
        }

        return base.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but that code assume the XML exist on a disk, I want to validate before i save the XML document.

Comment: You can change the method to read the the xml from a stream instead, so you would read from a memory stream etc.

Comment: Do you think you could show an example with MemoryStream I'm not sure how you are suppose to use it.