# XML deserialization using XSD/Code generation - Parsing Error

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xml-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize an XML document using an XSD. The error I am getting is:

> "There is an error in XML document (22, 8)."

The `InnerException` is

> "Input string was not in a correct format."

Now, row 22 of my sample XML document just has this:

```
<PremiumPaymentDate>2012-08-08</PremiumPaymentDate>
```

Nothing wrong with that as far as I can see. The XSD specifies this row similarly like:

```
<xs:element name="PremiumPaymentDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"/>
```

And the property it's trying to map to looks like this:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, DataType="date")]
public System.DateTime PremiumPaymentDate {
    get {
        return this.premiumPaymentDateField;
    }
    set {
        this.premiumPaymentDateField = value;
    }
}
```

I've tried removing this field completely, regenerated the code file from the XSD, changing the XSD around, changing the `minOccurs` value, changing the format of the field, removing the field data completely, and nothing is working.

I'm also wondering why everything works up until row 22, because they are about 17 fields above this one that work fine, and a few of them are dates that are set up the same exact way. This one just doesn't want to parse for some reason.

Edit:

These dates work. These are above the date in question in the document. Here is the XSD for one that works:

```
<xs:element name="effectivedate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="1"/>
```

And here is the sample XML for the same one:

```
<effectivedate>2012-06-08</effectivedate>
```

And the code property for it:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, DataType="date")]
        public System.DateTime effectivedate {
            get {
                return this.effectivedateField;
            }
            set {
                this.effectivedateField = value;
            }
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide more code of your mapping (properties with DateTime which works)?

Comment: Sure...I'll edit my question.

Comment: Is this working when you change name of property from `effectivedate` to `EffectiveDate` ? (same in xml node and XSD definition).

Comment: There are a bunch of fields that it's getting through that are proper case. The date one I posted just happens not to have it, but others do that work. I thought that as well, haha.

Comment: in debug string of `PremiumPaymentDate` don't have any empty signs like `&nbsp;` or simply whitespace? Before you try to Parse this value use a `Trim()` method on it.

Comment: Before anything, did you try to validate the XML against the XSD? If it passes validation, you've run into a bug... then you'll be asking for a workaround; I would try to reproduce with an XSD and XML, then post that here. Otherwise, the XML may need fixing.

Comment: @Petru Gardea seems to be right. I tried to reproduce your error scenario but could not, always work. Source: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49510149/stackoverflow/dotnet/Q11651260ConsApp.7z

Comment: How would I perform the validation?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557190/validate-xml-with-xsd-file).

Comment: This may be a stretch, but sometimes line numbers as reported during validation can be off. Could it be a different node with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the previous node exists?

Probably the error is not in this node but your schema is expecting some else node which comes before this node but it is not exists.

for example if your xsd is below

```
...
<xs:element name="someelsenode" type="xs:date" minOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="missingnode" type="xs:date" minOccurs="1"/>
<xs:element name="effectivedate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="1"/>
...
```

but your xml looks like as below

```
...
<someelsenode>2012-06-08</someelsenode>
<effectivedate>2012-06-08</effectivedate>
...
```

then you can get "There is an error in XML document (22, 8)." error. this will refer the correct node line and column but actually what it is trying to say is the other node is not there.

so before `<effectivedate>2012-06-08</effectivedate>` there must be `<missingnode>2012-06-08</missingnode>`